# Fade UIView and Switch UIView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

This is how I switch from one UIView to another UIView: `self.view = MyView;`
How would I fade out a view to my `MySecondView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use UIView's build in transition code to cross dissolve between them.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:MySecondView duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // What to do when its finished.
}];
```

You can also use the regular animation options with something like this. I haven't tested this code as I'm not in front of Xcode but I use it all the time for labels and things without default animations.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [self.view setAlpha:0.0];
    self.view = mySecondView;
    [self.view setAlpha:1.0];
}];
```

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted, but how would I fade it back into `MyFirstView`?

Comment: Just reverse the code? Or if you mean like right away you can do `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoReverse`. Im not super clear on what you mean.

Comment: I have tried `[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:MyFirstView duration:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // What to do when its finished.
    }];` But nothing happens.

Comment: I fixed by changing ``transitionFromView:**self.view**` to **MySecondView**

Comment: Then to fade back you just do selfview to MyFirstView?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that it's not a good idea to do things like self.view = MyView to change screens. By the time you get to a few screens, your viewController will be filled with spaghetti code. You should consider presenting new view controllers that manage their views. One way you can do fade is as follows:

- Fade the current view to black (with animation)
- In the view controller that you are going to push use viewWillAppear to fade the view to black as well
- Push/Present the view controller without animations.
- Now use the viewDidAppear method of the newly presented view controller to fade in the view (with animation).